# opening an embedded html in an external browser in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, embedded-resource

Is it possible to embed an html as a resource and launch it using an external browser in C#? I don't want to use a webbrowser control just for this html in the project. It is a simple help file, if possible, I would like to embed as a resource, so that I can have a single EXE to deal with.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use a webbrowser control? Seems the most obvious solution if you don't want the file to be external.

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Because there are 2 ways to skin this cat.

Comment: @Adam . Just didnt want to add more code for this..if there is a simpler way..

Comment: @code4life This is just .NET 3.5 WinForms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag and drop the resource html file into your Resources tab, like this:

[image: Resources View]

Then use the following code:

```
var txt = Properties.Resources.sample;
var fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");

var fs = File.CreateText(fileName);
fs.Write(txt);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();

Process.Start(fileName);
```

That's about it...

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct for the simplicity...thanks!

Comment: Simple is the best.. `Properties` contains all the behind-the-scenes plumbing code in a nice little black box, lol

Comment: Just change `Path.Combine()` to `Path.ChangeExtension()`

Comment: @PeetBrits: I don't get what you're saying... how does that obviate the need to write the resource out to a temp file?  :S

Comment: @code4life: What I meant was that `Path.Combine(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");` will try to create `...\tmp3788.tmp\.html`, but `Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html")` will create `...\tmp3798.html`.

Comment: The four rows related to creating, writing, flushing, and closing the file can be replaced with a single `File.WriteAllText()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void ExtractFileFromResources(String filename, String location)
        {
          //  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            System.Reflection.Assembly a =  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                        Stream resFilestream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
            if (resFilestream != null)
            {
                 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(resFilestream);
                 FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create); 
                 BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                 byte[] ba = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
                resFilestream.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length);
              bw.Write(ba);
            br.Close();
            bw.Close();
            resFilestream.Close();
        }

    }

 string path = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\file.html");

 ExtractFileFromResources("file.html", path);


 Process.Start(path);
```